# How can I verify after updating the ID in admob value shall I need to change unit id as well (android)

Tags: android, admob

I need to update the value for the admob, here If I modify the id how can i know the changes.

And If i change the value, shall i need to change the UnitId as well. Or it will be same as before? Kindly clarify. It was new

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"/>

My Ids are like below

    ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxxInterstitial
    ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxNative advanced
    ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

An **app ID is a unique ID** number assigned to your apps when they're added to AdMob. The app ID is used to identify your apps.

An **ad unit ID is a unique ID** number assigned to each of your ad units when they're created in AdMob. The ad unit ID is added to your app's code and used to identify ad requests from the ad unit.

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356431?hl=en

**Do not change the app ID.** Change Individual ad unit IDs. Check above link to find app ID and ad unit ID on admob console